# Can't define vertices

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to draw a triangle in this way, but I keep messing up the part, where I have to choose my vertices. Can somebody tell me where I went wrong?

```
from graphics import GraphicsWindow

triangle1= [[150,50], [250,50],[200,130]]


win = GraphicsWindow(400, 400)
canvas = win.canvas()
canvas.setOutline("blue")
canvas.drawPolygon(triangle1, canvas)
last = len(triangle1) - 1
for i in range(last):
    start = triangle1[i]
    end = triangle1[i+1]
    canvas.drawLine(start[0], start[1], end[0], end[1])
start =triangle1[last]
end = triangle1[0]
canvas.drawLine(start[0], start[1], end[0], end[1])
win.wait()
```

Comment: Why are you converting your coordinates to strings?

Comment: It was just to test something out. I forgot to remove it. but the problem is that if I do this with a list it gives me an error. But if i fill in these coordinates individually it works without problem.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: In any case, I'd guess that `canvas.drawPolygon(triangle1, canvas)` the error. Rest seems fine.

Comment: the error is ' that at least 3 vertices have to be chosen' although i defined them in the list 'triangle1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EzGraphics, try:

```
triangle1 = [150, 50, 250, 50, 200, 130]
canvas.drawPolygon(triangle1)
```

or

```
triangle1 = [(150, 50), (250, 50), (200, 130)]
canvas.drawPolygon(triangle1)
```

Comment: @MblastSt great, glad I could help :) You might consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark if it solved your problem.